# How to set up my model associations so that Answer has_one :option and Option has_many :answers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to set up my model so that Answer has_one :option, and Option has_many :answers.  They are joined through an AnsweredOptions table.  Here are the three models:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :answered_options
  has_one :option, through: :answered_options, source: :options

  belongs_to :question

end

class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :answered_options
  has_many :answers, through: :answered_options, source: :answers
end

class AnsweredOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :option
end
```

I first tried both the above models without source, but I am getting the same error which I will share below in a minute.

schema for answered_options:

```
create_table "answered_options", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "answer_id"
    t.integer  "option_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Here is the error I get when I run Answer.first.option in the console:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) :options in model AnsweredOption. Try 'has_many :option, :through => :answered_options, :source => <name>'
```

Here is the error I get when I run Option.first.answers:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) :answers in model AnsweredOption. Try 'has_many :answers, :through => :answered_options, :source => <name>
```

I added the source: option in my associations after getting these error messages, but that did not change anything.  What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need Answer has_one :option, and Option has_many :answers. You do not need AnsweredOption. You just need to create a simply has_one and has_many relationship.

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :option
  belongs_to :question
end

class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :answers
end
```

You do not need to create the AnsweredOption class. It is meant to serve as a link between the Option and Answer classes, but it is used in the case of many-to-many relationship, like an option has many answers, and an answer has many options.

Comment: and you'll need `option_id` on the answers table to serve as the foreign key, of course.

Comment: I changed it to how you suggested except I had to use belongs_to :option instead of has_one :option for Answer, Is this the proper way to go about it or am I doing something wrong with my has_one association?

Comment: there are some differences between `belongs_to` and `has_one`. But functionally, they are very similar. If `belongs_to` work for you, just use that. Here is a [link](http://requiremind.com/differences-between-has-one-and-belongs-to-in-ruby-on-rails/) if you want to read more about the differences between the two.